# Cartoon episode where the protagonists encounter a futuristic shopping mall with no exit

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I vaguely remember seeing an episode of a children's cartoon series on German television in the 90s where the group of protagonists finds a futuristic looking mall. Upon entering it, they are welcomed by some sort of host (I seem to remember it as a hovering robot, but that could be nonsense), and when they turn around, the entrance behind them is gone. None of the shoppers in the mall are aware that "the outside" exists, and they seem confused by or even laugh at the idea of an exit. The episode then revolves around trying to exit the mall and proving to the shoppers that the outside world exists. In the end, I think the ceiling opens and everybody looks at the sky and the sun in awe.

I remember the animation style to be very colorful and typical of 80s and 90s cartoons for children. It was definitely drawn and not computer animated. Other than that, I cannot remember too much about the style, and I'm not entirely sure if it was Japanese-style or western-style, but I'm leaning towards the latter. As mentioned before, I saw it on German TV at some time in the (mid) 90s, and it was professionally dubbed in German.

Despite the somewhat menacing scenario and serious undertones about consumerism, I think the general tone was rather light. It might even be (but I'm really not sure there) that the host apologizes in the end, making the happy ending even more harmonic. I suppose the target audience was something like age 7-12.

I hardly remember anything about the characters. The group of protagonists consisted of around three to five humanoids (probably just humans, but I'm not entirely sure). They were relatively young (but I'm not sure if they were children or teenagers) and I think there were both boys and girls. I'm not sure about their ethnicity, but I think they were (mostly?) white.

Any help in identifying the TV show and the episode is highly appreciated.

PS: I went through [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/117472) and tried to answer all of its questions as good as I could. If my question is missing any information that this checklist asks for, then this means that I cannot remember anything about it.

Comment: I think that it might have been a Digimon episode like that. Can you check if you remember anything about the style?

Comment: @jo1storm The animation style of Digimon doesn't ring a bell. Also, the first season of Digimon aired in 2000 and I am fairly certain that I saw this episode a few years earlier. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Am I the only one who read the title and thought, "Hotel California"?

Comment: Archie's Weird Mysteries had an episode where the cast were under some spell in an evil mall, with only Jughead not affected.  He beats the mall "host" by eating Pop's burgers instead of the ones the mall has available.

Comment: @Basya Cartoon episode where the protagonists encounter a futuristic shopping mall where they can check out any time they like but they can never leave.

Answer (score 2):

Widget? Iirc the episode had an alarm where shoppers had to buy new clothes or they would get a ticket.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to provide the title of the specific episode, and to say a bit more about the plot of the episode, to give us a better idea of how closely it matches the description given in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! There seems to be an episode called Maller Crawlers, which sounds promising, but I can't find more info on it right now. I'll have to dig a little deeper later.

Comment: "26. Der intergalaktische Kaufrausch
Staffel 2, Folge 13 (22 Min.)
Ein gigantisches Einkaufszentrum im All zieht alle in seinen Bann. Auch Widgets Freunde geraten in Kaufrausch. Der kleine Weltenwächter hat alle Mühe, die Menschen wieder zu anderen Freuden zu überreden. (Text: Premiere)
Deutsche TV-PremiereFr 02.04.1993 PRO 7" (https://www.fernsehserien.de/widget-der-kleine-waechter/episodenguide/staffel-2/6435) That's the most detailed info I've found and it sounds very fitting indeed. Now I just have to find the video somewhere...

Comment: For what it's worth: That series is called "Widget the World Watcher" in english, and the title of that episode is "Maller Crawlers" (S2E13).